# How to listen to a computed property in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to disable a button based on a computed property from the View Model, but is only disabled after the view is reloaded.

This is the View Model :

```
  class VerifyFieldViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @ObservedObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()
    func isValidFirstName() -> Bool {
        guard coreDataViewModel.savedDetails.first?.firstName?.count ?? 0 > 0 else {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    func isValidLastName() -> Bool {
        guard coreDataViewModel.savedDetails.first?.lastName?.count ?? 0 > 0 else {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    var isFirstNameValid : String {
        if isValidFirstName() {
       return ""
        } else {
        return "Name is empty"
        }
    }
    
    var isLastNameValid : String {
        if isValidLastName() {
       return ""
        } else {
        return "Surname is empty"
        }
    }
    
   var isSignUpComplete: Bool {
        if !isValidFirstName() || !isValidLastName() {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    }
```

This is how I am disabling the button .

```
struct CartsView: View {
    @State var onboardingState: Int = 0
    @StateObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var verifyFieldViewModel = VerifyFieldViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            switch onboardingState {

            case 0 :
                VStack {
                detailOrder
                    .transition(transition)
                Spacer()
                bottomButton
                    .padding(30)
                }
            case 2 :
                VStack {
                detailOrder2
                    .transition(transition)
                    Spacer()
                    bottomButton
                        .padding(30)
                        .opacity(verifyFieldViewModel.isSignUpComplete ? 1 : 0.6)
                        .disabled(!verifyFieldViewModel.isSignUpComplete)
                }
            default:
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
}
}
```

This is the Core Data View Model :

```
class CoreDataViewModel  : ObservableObject {
    let manager = CoreDataManager.instance
    @Published var savedDetails : [Details] = []
    init() {
        fetchSavedDetails()
    }
    func fetchSavedDetails() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<Details>(entityName: "Details")
        do {
            savedDetails = try manager.context.fetch(request)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error fetching \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    
    func saveContext() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.manager.save()
            self.fetchSavedDetails()
        }
        }

}
```

NOTE : It works, but only when the view is reloaded.

EDITED : I updated the question to make it easier to understand. Hope that you can help me now.
EDITED2: Added Core Data View Model .

Comment: You don't show enough code here to reproduce your issue, but in general, your view will be rendered again once a `@Published` property on the view model is changed or if it's `objectWillChange` publisher is manually called (assuming your view model is an `ObservableObject` and accessed via `@StateObject` or `@ObservedObject`. Your computed property will get called again at that point too. If you include a [mre], it's likely someone can show you exactly what to change if that's not enough information.

Comment: @jnpdx I have updated the question. Can you check now ?

Comment: It is not an [mre], so still lots of guesswork. Nested ObservableObjects won’t work as expected — you’ll have to call objectWillChange.send manually when the child object changes.

Comment: You have to use @FetchRequest to use Core Data in SwiftUI otherwise the screen won't update correctly.

Comment: I added the Core Data View Model if it helps. You can check the updated question .@jnpdx

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above you don't need a computed property in this case. I made a small example of Login procedure which demonstrates the same behavior.

```
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var username: String = ""
    @Published var password: String = ""
    
    var isValid: Bool {
        (username.isNotEmpty && password.isNotEmpty)
    }
    
    func login() {
       // perform login
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var vm: LoginViewModel = LoginViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            TextField("User name", text: $vm.username)
            TextField("Password", text: $vm.password)
            Button("Login") {
                vm.login()
            }.disabled(!vm.isValid)
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I forgot to add in the questions, my variable come from the Core Date, so I cant make them @Published. Check the edited questions to see how i am making field validation

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you check now ?

Comment: It is hard to tell since CoreDataViewModel is not shown. You may have to use NSFetchedResultsController to hook up to the events of CoreData managed objects. 
https://youtu.be/gGM_Qn3CUfQ

Comment: I added the Core Data View Model if it helps. You can check the updated question .